# Search and Replace String from text file Ubuntu

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep, xargs

I have to replace following String

```
//@Config(manifest
```

with below string,

```
@Config(manifest
```

So this i created following regex

```
\/\/@Config\(manifest
```

And tried

```
grep -rl \/\/@Config\(manifest . | xargs sed -i "\/\/@Config\(manifest@Config\(manifest/g"
```

But i am getting following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 38: Unmatched ( or \(
```

I have to search recursively and do this operation, though i am stuck with above error.

Comment: why extra `manifest$` ?

Comment: That waas added by mistake, removed it though still getting same error

Comment: can you even update the error to new one, as the char value will change

Comment: getting same error sed: -e expression #1, char 39: Unmatched ( or \(

Comment: try this `grep -l \/\/@Config\(manifest . | xargs sed -i "s/\/\/@Config(manifest/@Config(manifest/g"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grep -rl '//@Config(manifest' | xargs sed -i 's|//@Config(manifest|@Config(manifest|g'
```

- Specifying `.` for current directory is optional for `grep -r`
- `sed` allows **Any character other than backslash or newline** to be used as delimiter

**Edit**

If file name contains spaces, use

```
grep -rlZ '//@Config(manifest' | xargs -0 sed -i 's|//@Config(manifest|@Config(manifest|g'
```

**Explanation** (assumes GNU version of commands)

- **grep**

  - `-r` performs recursive search
  - `-l` option outputs only filenames instead of matched patterns
  - `-Z` outputs a *zero byte* (ASCII NUL character) after each file name instead of usual newline
  - `'pattern'` by default, grep uses BRE (basic regular expression) where characters like `(` do not have special meaning and hence need not be escaped
- `xargs -0` tells `xargs` to separate arguments by the ASCII NUL character
- **sed**

  - `-i` inplace edit, use `-i.bkp` if you want to create backup of original files
  - `s|pattern|replace|g` the `g` flag tells `sed` to search and replace all occurrences. `sed` also defaults to BRE and so no need to escape `(`. Using `\(` would mean start of capture groups and hence the error when it doesn't find the closing `\)`

Comment: it's not working for recursive directories if any directory have space in it's name

Comment: Thanks, it worked, though It would be great if you explain the command in the answer so others can understand it easily and it will also improve the answer quality

Comment: Thanks for improving the quality of answer, it would help so many in future.