# VIM - Update multiple files only in the result of search

Tags: vim, replace, macvim

Here is my problem:

I have large project, with filtered out lot of files and directories from `ag` searcher.

I need to update multiple files, but only files that I am interested with are those available for searcher, so what I want to do is do `:argdo` or `:buffdo` but on the collection received from `ag` search request.

1. `:Ag something_to_change` -> result contain a list of 10 files
2. Grep this result and do a substitution command only on those 10 files

I imagine that it would look like: `:Ag something_to_change | :args | :argdo %s/something_to_change/somthing_changed/ge | update`

Thanks for any suggestions on that

Comment: if you do not mind command line solution, [example for grep + sed combo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39218941/search-and-replace-string-from-text-file-ubuntu/39219118#39219118)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a reasonably recent build (7.4.858 and up) you can use the built-in `:cdo` or `:cfdo` commands:

```
:Ag something_to_chnage
:cfdo %s/something_to_change/somthing_changed/ge
```

See `:help :cdo` and `:help :cfdo`.

If you don't, my plugin [vim-qf](https://github.com/romainl/vim-qf) comes with `:Doline` and `:Dofile` which do the same as `:cdo` and `:cfdo`.

Comment: Amazing, that helped!, Thanks!